# Combine two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a basic question about list-manipulation. I have two lists:

```
l1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
l2 = {a, b, c}
```

The desired outcome is: {{a,1,1},{b,2,2},{c,3,3}}

I tried with Transpose but didn't get it to work; any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MapThread[Prepend, {l1, l2}]
```

or

```
Flatten /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]
```